# How to sort folders by icons, rather by name of folder?

Tags: windows, icons, sorting

I created icons that are labelled with numbers, but I would like to name them not by the associated number.
It creates a problem because the icons will be alphabetically sorted and in thus in disorder...

For example, if Folders are named like this:

```
Folder with "Icon 1" named: Romania
Folder with "Icon 2" named: Sweden
Folder with "Icon 3" named: Hungary
Folder with "Icon 4" named: Italy
Folder with "Icon 5" named: Austria
```

They will be sorted by their names and the icon would be listed in this order:
5 3 4 1 2

Is there a way to name them but have the icons sorted like I want?

Comment: You mean other than `1 Romania` `2 Sweden` ……

Comment: Icons are just pictures.  You can sort by name, date, size and so on, but I do not think you can sort by picture,

Comment: Per @Tetsujin and I would add if more than 9 add trailing zero(s) or 2 will be sorted after 10. eg: `10`,`2`,`21`,`37`,`9` **vs.** `02`,`09`,`10`,`21`,`37`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you only want this functdionality for folders, you can populate the `Comment` column with the corresponding numbers and then sort on that column. This would be done by adding the line `InfoTip=<digit{s}>` following the `IconResource =...` line. If this suits your needs but you have a large number of existing cutomized folders, I can post an answer with PowerShell code to pull the number from the icon filename and modify the file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Though you cannot sort on an *image*, you *can* sort on additional columns in Windows Explorer. For example, you can add *Tags* to Windows *Explorer*. Then use a tool such as free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) to edit the [IPTC](https://smartframe.io/blog/what-is-iptc-metadata-everything-you-need-to-know/) and/or [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) information for each file. *Keywords* in IPTC are visible in *Explorer* as *Tags*.

[image: IrfanView]

[image: Use column Tags to sort]

There are other applications to edit that data, such as command-line [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) by Phil Harvey and [ExifToolGUI](https://exiftool.org/gui/), that allow *batch* editing, so one could add keyword "Magyarország" to *all* photos in the *Hungary* folder, and then edit each only to add other key words to differentiate them, saving time.

Realistically, many photographers prefer to use [photo-organizing tools](https://www.pixpa.com/blog/photo-organiser) to catalog all their pictures. These tools help build a database so you could search and sort on different fields, or even perform a search such as [*Select * from 2022-PICS where upper(SUBJECT) like "*BIRD*" and upper(COUNTRY) IN ("ENGLAND", "IRELAND")*](https://news.softpedia.com/news/Organize-Your-Images-in-a-MySQL-Database-70910.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Not possible, except by using another column
that has a similar effect.

In more detail : Explorer does not have an "Icon" column to be
sorted by it.
It's even impossible to add user-defined columns or modify columns
using add-ons. All the ways to do it are completely blocked
by Microsoft, leaving as only option the adding of new tabs inside
the Properties dialog, which doesn't help here.

I suggest to sort using the "Type" column. The type of the file,
the same as its icon, are derived from the program that is
defined as the handler for the file-type (by its extension).

This will have the same effect, grouping the files by their icons.
You will not be able to control the order in which the groups
of files will be displayed.

Comment: Valid, but really a comment. One *could* theoretically use OCR to change the image data to Exif data -- but as stated above, the game ain't worth the candle.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Don't you think that your comment is not going too far? Doing OCR on the icons and adding the images as tags???

Comment: Calm everybody :D You are not modifying Explorer, @SeñorCMasMas, you are extending it in the limits allowed by Microsoft. But maybe you can add an icon column...? (not overusing tag column I mean) In another hand, harrymc should be less categorical on some assertions as it may hurt said power users.

Comment: @gildux: We're very calm, and I have full respect for the knowledgeable Señor CMasMas. I have modified my answer with more data and a new suggestion that answers fully the poster's request without the need to update his files. I suggest that we all delete all our comments above.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, your new answer is better. Votes are anonymous and can't be changed after some minutes (five or fifteen, I can't remember.) In another hand, downvotes cost (2 reputation points) for the voter. I upvote to compensate.

Comment: @gildux: Thanks for the upvote and the good will. Note: Votes can be retracted if the answer was modified in the meantime.

Comment: nope @harrymc .. not mine.  I assure you.  I don't use downvotes like that. :) My OTHER comments deleted